# removing redundant queries from laravel / eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In a laravel code base I'm working with there's this line of code:

```
    if ($limit === '-1') {
        $items = $query->get();

        if ($items->count() < 1) {
            return Paginator::make([], 0, Config::get('api.result_limit'));
        }

        return $query->paginate($items->count());
    }
```

$query is a `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasManyThrough` object.

Anyway, the problem is that a `SELECT table_name.*` is being performed twice. `$query->get()` does it and then `$query->paginate` does a `SELECT COUNT(*)` (which itself is redundant since we already have the count from the first query) and a `SELECT table_name.*, table_name.*`. ie. it's just excessively redundant and I'm trying to remove that redundancy.

Here's what I tried.

1. `return $items` right after `$query->get()`. Unfortunately, doing so yielded the following error:

   ```
   Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::getCollection()
   ```

   $query->paginate() returns a `\MyApp\Services\Pagination\Paginator` object which itself extends (`\Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator`) whereas $query->get() returns a `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` object.

   If I could somehow convert `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` to `\Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator` I think that'd do the trick but if that is possible idk how.
2. Doing `return $query->paginate(99999999)` right after the `if ($limit === '-1')`. That works but I'd rather not specify a hard limit. I don't specify a limit when doing a SELECT with SQL I'm writing and I don't think I should have to specify one here either. I tried `return $query->paginate(-1)` but that gave an error.

Any ideas?

Comment: your code is redundant. you are getting all the items from the database. and then you are retrieving the same with `paginate`. so it will be redundant. what actually you are trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to eliminate that redundancy. I tried `return $query->paginate(-1)` but that gave an error. `$query->paginate(9999999)` works but I'd rather not have to specify a hard limit, even if it's a really big one.

Comment: the question i want to ask is, you have all the items in hand. why you are calling `pagination`?

Comment: If $limit !== '-1' then pagination is done. Maybe the -1 "no limit" thing was done as an after thought and it was decided that going to each of the controllers to have each of them do a $limit !== '-1' check it was just easier to add the above code to the base abstract controller that the rest inherit from idk

Comment: there's some logical flaw here. you are retreiving all the data only to get the total number of items. then, in `paginate()`, you are putting that total number. so in practicality, your `?page=1` will hold every data. then what's the use of pagination when you are showing all the data in every instance? It is defeating both the purpose of `get()` and `paginate()`. you are using both yet, misusing both.

Comment: It's `?page=-1` that holds every bit of data. `?page=1`, `?page=2`, etc do *not* hold every bit of data and *are* in fact paginated. Using `get()` is more appropriate for `?page=-1`, yes, but outside of the snippet of code that I posted (but in the same method) a pagination object is returned. I can't just return `get()` for one and `paginate()` for the other because the objects that each return are different (as explained in my OP).

Comment: The *reason* pagination is being done in the code snippet is so that code written that's expecting a pagination object can work. Your criticisms are rather like me attacking someone for writing an SFTP client as a drop in replacement for an FTP client, with the same API functions, etc. "The two protocols are fundamentally different!" is what you're essentially saying as though that somehow makes the notion of a drop in replacement invalid or a worthless endeavour.

Comment: i didn't say worthless. i said _misuse_. there's a difference. none the less, you can paginate a collection by `forPage(int $page, int $perPage)` method. you don't need to run a `paginate` again.

Comment: I don't want the collection paginated. I want all the results returned. I just want the result to have a `getCollection()` method whilst still containing every single result. `?page=-1` *is* supposed to return every bit of data. I'm not trying to add LIMITs to it. If page is positive pagination will take place and I'm trying to maintain backwards compatibility with controllers that are expecting the `getCollection()` object to exist whilst still being able to add the ability for *all* the data to be returned.

Comment: What I want is for the result of the code snippet I posted to be pseudo-paginated. ie. I want it to hold all the results but for the caller to still be able to treat it as a paginated object for purposes of BC. There are maybe a hundred or so places where `getCollection()` is called. It's easier to hack up the code snippet I posted than it is to modify each and every call to `getCollection()`.